# How to use github files in spinnaker pipeline

Tags: github, spinnaker

Does anyone know how can we download GitHub repository as a part of spinnaker pipeline.

We have few scripts which are present in Github and I want to get those scripts during spinnaker pipeline execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use the [Github](https://www.spinnaker.io/setup/artifacts/github/) artifact
2. You can use the Script or Run Command [Stage](https://www.spinnaker.io/setup/features/script-stage/) to obtain the scripts and execute them.